# How do I get Vim to automatically put ending braces?

Tags: vim, autocomplete

While editing `.scm` files it would be great if Vim would automatically put the ending brace `)` as soon as I start `(`. How do I do this?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can map the opening brace to your liking:

```
:imap ( ()<left>
```

Comment: The plugins mentioned in the other answers have the advantage of behaving "intelligently" when typing the corresponding closing ")". If this is not needed, then I'd also go with the straigt forward map.

Comment: Some plugins also : - don't expand within comment and string contexts, - define a way to surround the selection with a pair of brackets, - inserts a placeholder/marker in order to jump past the closing bracket (which is consistent with most snippets/templates expander plugins).

Comment: Is there a way to only do that at the end of a line? Sometimes it is more annoying than useful but with this, i would use it gladly...

Answer (score 33):

Try to use [AutoClose](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1849) plugin.

Comment: Not to be confused with the other, less aggressive (and less annoying, IMO), [AutoClose](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2009) by Thiago Alves.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall +1, your listed version is much less annoying. I came here looking for an alternative to the one in Mykola's answer because of it's quirks.

Comment: FYI, This plugin seems to work fine but for me it introduced the "laggy" `<ESC>` behavior. So avoid if you care about this.

Answer (score 13):

The simplest answer is to include a map. Eg.:

```
:inoremap ( ()<left>
```

The problem is that you would need to add one entry for each symbol you want automatically closed ('{','[','"',etc). Besides, plugins are normally more smart, providing things like detecting the "closing" character and not repeating it.

The problem with the solution above and *most* plugins, is that they tend break the undo sequence ([gundo](http://sjl.bitbucket.org/gundo.vim/) anyone?), as explained in[:help ins-special-special](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/insert.html#ins-special-special).

Here is list of plugins that do what you ask (from [vimtips](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Automatically_append_closing_characters)):

- [delimitMate](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2754) by Israel Chauca Fuentes (configurable, and doesn't break undo/redo/repeat, but - break iabbr) also on [GitHub](https://github.com/Raimondi/delimitMate)
- [AutoClose](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1849) by Karl Guertin (auto-closes specific hard-coded characters, but doesn't break undo/redo/repeat)
- [AutoClose](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2009) by Thiago Alves (configurable, but breaks undo/redo/repeat)
- [auto-pairs](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3599) Auto Pairs by Miao Jiang (configurable, but breaks undo/redo/repeat)
- [ClosePairs](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2373) by Edoardo Vacchi (configurable, but breaks undo/redo/repeat)
- [smartinput](https://github.com/kana/vim-smartinput) by Kana Natsuno (configurable, but breaks undo/redo/repeat)

Besides [vimtips](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Automatically_append_closing_characters), there is [another nice explanation of the issue](http://sharats.me/vim-undo-breaks-with-auto-close-plugins.html) on the web.

Comment: For anyone else who finds this in the future, I just started using auto-pairs, and unless I'm understanding the terminology wrong it didn't break my undo or history. Best one out of this list! It also handles deleting pairs on backspace!

Comment: Which Vim version? Last time I checked there still wasn't a solution letting undo/redo/repeat work correctly with auto-closing in Vim 7.4 and onward. A few plugins had a hack using setline() that worked in earlier Vim versions.

Answer (score 11):

I needed one too, and I already tried a few of the plug-ins:

AutoClose, http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1849, is a bit aggressive.

simple pairs, http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2339, depends on Python. If you are on Linux it is not a problem, but on Windows it can be a trouble to match the Vim version to the Python interpreter you have.

My advice would be ClosePairs, that you can find at http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2373 which has been working perfectly for me. It is simple and useful.

Answer (score 8):

There are many tips and plugins on the subject. Have a look at the [relevant entry](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Automatically_append_closing_characters) in the vimtips site.

Answer (score 6):

I'm presently using [auto-pairs](https://github.com/jiangmiao/auto-pairs) and it works quite very well.

The issues of the the plugin breaking undo/redo/repeat seem to persist among some of the plugins listed above but i don't think its much of an issue (well, at least not to me at the moment).

*Just one caveat though, i wasn't able to use :helptags to generate the help file with this plugin as at the time of writing this.*

Answer (score 3):

Check out this new plugin: [vim-autoclose by Townk](https://github.com/Townk/vim-autoclose). The previously mentioned [AutoClose](https://github.com/vim-scripts/AutoClose) was to aggressive, sometimes behaving in an undesirable way.

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem with using this (via the imap or one of the scripts). You won't be able to repeat the complete edit by using the `.` command.

`e.g. (foo) with . only gets you foo, without the brackets.`

It works fine if you insert the brackets normally, as two characters.

Answer (score 1):

You can try downloading the following plugin
[AutoClose : Inserts matching bracket, paren, brace or quote](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1849)

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/vim-scripts/Auto-Pairs

Tested this plugin for undu redo. 2013 It just works. Also with python-mode plugin.

Answer (score 0):

There is a new plugin by cohama:

**`lexima.vim`** ([github](https://github.com/cohama/lexima.vim))

(not yet on vim.org)

**This plugin supports the `.`command!**
Afaik, this is the only plugin supporting this.

Also the undo/redo sequence works.